# Why should I use std::less<T>() or other operator classes instead of operator<?

Tags: c++, stl, functor

The `<functional>` header in the C++ STL provides several operator classes. I've been told I should use these operator classes rather than a class' equivalent `operatorXX`. Why is that the case? What's the issue with using `operator<` directly?

For instance, say we have a `std::vector<string> v` that we would like to sort. Using the `sort()` function, I could write the following:

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), operator<);
```

But I've been told that it's better to write

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), less<string>())
```

What is the advantage of using these operator classes defined in `<functional>`?

Comment: Because `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), operator<);` simply doesn't work.